# Does Mirth Open-Source support channels that work over https (using ssl)

Tags: ssl, https, open-source, mirth, mirth-connect

This is basically a yes/no question.  I am investigating Mirth Connect for my company but, at least to start out, we need this to work using only the Open Source version.

Of course, HIPAA requires that all message sending be done over HTTPS (using SSL).

Does the Open Source version support HTTPS out of the box.

I looked in the Administrator Channel setup and did not see an obvious way to force connections to use HTTPS.  So, if it IS supported, how do you set it up?

Comment: Free version does not support that, you need Mirth Appliance or purchase SSL connector separately. There are workarounds however.

Comment: Can you point me to a URL that explains the workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The open source distribution does support sending out via HTTPS using the HTTP Sender. However it just uses the default Java truststore, so any custom certs you trust will have to manually be added to cacerts. Advanced options like hostname verification, mutual auth, etc. aren't supported with the open source distribution.

The [SSL Manager extension](https://www.nextgen.com/Interoperability/Mirth-Solutions/Connect-Extensions?extension=ssl-manager) expands on this, adding TLS support for ***all*** socket-based source and destination connectors:

- DICOM Listener / Sender
- File Reader / Writer
- HTTP Listener / Sender
- TCP Listener / Sender
- Web Service (SOAP) Listener / Sender
- [Email Reader](https://www.nextgen.com/Interoperability/Mirth-Solutions/Connect-Extensions?extension=email-reader) / SMTP Sender

It not only *enables* TLS but allows advanced fine-tuning options on a per-connector basis, like Hostname Verification, Mutual (Client) Auth, tweaking protocols / cipher suites, and more:

[image: SSL Settings]

On top of that it provides a one-stop shop for all trusted and local certificates / keypairs used across your server. You can even create entirely new certificates in the Administrator, generate a CSR, and import the reply from a CA.

Comment: However, am I correct in saying that to get the SSL Manager Extension will cost a minimum of $20K per year or can you buy/license JUST that extension?  In my opinion, if you answer that you have to have a commercial license to use the SSL Manager then that makes Mirth Open-Source almost useless.

Comment: It is possible to do HTTPS with Mirth Connect open source. I have done it with 3.3.1 version.

Comment: @VibinGuvera explain how.

Comment: @SethSpearman We have an offering called the Core Extension Bundle that doesn't require a support license, and includes the SSL Manager, Channel History, and Message Generator extensions. More info [here!](https://www.nextgen.com/products-and-services/integration-engine)

Comment: The link to the PDF which describes the Core Extension Bundle is here: https://ng.nextgen.com/secure-integration-lower-cost-core-bundle It doesn't indicate price however.